# Fazer redirect 301 em urls especificas

Tags: php, htaccess, redirecionamento

Como faço em htacess redirect 301 ?
Mas em urls especificas, eu troquei meu dominio, e migrei os posts por exemplo:
meusite.com.br/artigo/nomedoartigo
meusite2.com.br/artigo/nomedoartigo

Fazer um redirect 301 só quando tiver /artigo/
Ai quando pessoal que acessar o url antigo para ver um artigo por exemplo, vai direto pro meusite2.com.br
é possivel?

Comment: Tente assim: `ErrorDocument 301 http://meusite2.com.br`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
RewriteEngine on

#Somente se for o host antigo...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^meusite\.com\.br$ [NC]
#... redirecionar só quando tiver artigo/
RewriteRule ^artigo(/.*|$)  http://meusite2.com.br/artigo$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Explicação:

- `RewriteCond` define uma condição para executar a próxima `RewriteRule` se corresponde. Neste caso, se o host antigo `meusite.com.br`.

  - `NC` faz que ignore caixa alta/baixa.
- `^artigo(/.*|$)` casa:
  `^` - início da string
  `artigo` - literal
  `(/.*|$)` - um `/` seguido por qualquer texto, ou o fim da string
  o valor que corresponde à `(/.*|$)` é capturado em `$1`.
- `http://meusite2.com.br/artigo$1` o novo host, com o texto capturado na condição.
- Flags:

  - `R=301` - redirect 301.
  - `L` -  a regra atual deve ser aplicada imediatamente, sem considerar outras regras.
  - `NC` - faz que ignore caixa alta/baixa.